# Finding the mean of a uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

I have a random set $\{a,b,c\}$ and a second set $\{e,d\}$
I draw one number first number and one from the second

Letting $X_1$ denote the first number and $X_2$ the second number find, $E(X_1)$ and $E(X_2)$ and $E(X_1+X_2)$

Please please help, it might be obvious but I just can't work it out!

Comment: By uniform distribution do you mean that probability to pick a number from a set is equal to every number? i.e. $P(a)=P(b)=P(c)=1/3$?

Comment: Tomas - yes, I think he is referring to the Discrete uniform distribution (as opposed to the continuous one, that some of us are more used to).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29

Answer (score 1):

$E[X_1]$ and $E[X_2]$ are simply the averages of all the elements in each set, respectively. $E[X_1+X_2]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]$.

Answer (score 0):

As Tomas points out, $P(a) = P(b) = P(c) = \frac{1}{3}$. Thus,

$$E(X_1) = aP(a) + bP(b) + cP(c)$$

$$=\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$

You can apply the same method to work out $E(X_2)$.

As Vincent points out, the linearity of Expected Value over these uniform distributions gives

$$E(X_1+X_2) = E(X_1) + E(X_2)$$

[Alternatively, you could go through all the possibilities of $X_1+X_2$, i.e. the set {$a+d, a+e, b+d,b+e,c+d,c+e$}. There are six elements in this set and the probability of getting each is $\frac{1}{6}$, because the distribution is uniform. And you could compute $E(X_1+X_2)$ in a similar fashion as above.]

Comment: this is what I first thought but I figured it couldn't be that simple, thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome, Justin :-)